# Cannot import name 'User' from 'Locust' library

Tags: locust

I'm quite new to `Locust`, just starter tinkering with it a couple of days ago.

Previously I followed someone else's example which was using:

```
class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
   # Do stuff
```

But after reading more documentation I tried to use the `User` class and now I'm getting errors when I try to import the said class:

I just copy/pasted the example from the [docs](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/writing-a-locustfile.html#the-wait-time-attribute) to make sure I didn't have any typos:

```
from locust import User, TaskSet, task, between

class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):
    @task
    def my_task(self):
        print("executing my_task")

class MyUser(User):
    tasks = [MyTaskSet]
    wait_time = between(5, 15)
```

Response:

```
local_1          | [2020-05-07 00:54:07,494] c8343450b35a/ERROR/stderr: File "/src/locustfile.py", line 153, in <module>
local_1          | [2020-05-07 00:54:07,495] c8343450b35a/ERROR/stderr: 
local_1          | [2020-05-07 00:54:07,495] c8343450b35a/ERROR/stderr: from locust import User, TaskSet, task, between
local_1          | [2020-05-07 00:54:07,495] c8343450b35a/ERROR/stderr: 
local_1          | [2020-05-07 00:54:07,495] c8343450b35a/ERROR/stderr: ImportError
local_1          | [2020-05-07 00:54:07,495] c8343450b35a/ERROR/stderr: :
local_1          | [2020-05-07 00:54:07,495] c8343450b35a/ERROR/stderr: cannot import name 'User'
```

**NOTE**: I am running locust inside a docker container. And if I switch back to using:

```
class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehaviour # class UserBehaviour(TaskSet):
    wait_time = between(5.0, 9.0)
```

everything works fine.

This is my `requirements.txt` that I'm using:

```
locustio
influxdb==5.3.0
```

And I'm using the lastest version of `locust` docker image `locustio/locust:0.14.6`
So everything should be up-to-date.

1. Do you think this is the issue with the documentation and it should be updated or did I miss something and it's my fault?
2. I also noticed that there is a `Locust` class that I can import and it seems to behave the same way as the `User` class, I didn't see any docs the would mention the `Locust` class though..., does anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation at https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/ refers to locust 1.0 (currently available directly from github and as a pre-release package), where all `Locust` classes have been renamed `User`.

The current "stable" package (0.14.6) is documented here: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/

Hopefully that explains your situation.

See the changelog for more information about changes https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/changelog.html

Comment: Wow, dumb mistake ... I was looking at the wrong documentation.
Thank you, you have actually solved more than one issue for me!!!