# cannot import name 'HttpLocust' from 'locust.user.users'

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I have install locsut in my system as follows:
1. pip install -U setuptools
2. pip install -U --pre locustio
3. pip install locustio
But when i was importing 
from locust import HttpLocust ,  getting error that cannot import name 'HttpLocust' from 'locust.user.users'
    from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task, between
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
    import json

```
payload = {
    "Country": "india",
    "FB Id": "",
    "ScreenName": "vaibhav12222",
    "Password": "test123"
}


class UserBehavior( TaskSet ):

    @task( 1 )
    def home(self):
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        self.client.post( "/profile", data=json.dumps( payload ), headers=headers )
        # self.client.get("/register/riddhi")


class User( HttpLocust ):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    wait_time = between( 3, 5 )
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\saurabh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\saurabh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\SauraBh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\locust.exe__main__.py", line 5, in 
  File "c:\users\saurabh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\locust__init__.py", line 9, in 
    from .user.users import HttpUser, User, HttpLocust

ImportError: cannot import name 'HttpLocust' from 'locust.user.users'

(c:\users\saurabh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\locust\user\users.py)

Comment: I believe you are attempting to access httpLocust from this file - .venv/Lib/site-packages/locust/core.py  am I correct ? 
Its picking up wrong file. Check if you have locust.core and check pypath

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648175/cannot-import-name-user-from-locust-library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot import name 'User' from 'Locust' library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648175/cannot-import-name-user-from-locust-library)